# How to debug NSInternalInconsistencyException trying to load nib that doesn't exist?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

```
2012-09-07 19:31:07.938 BadgerNew[2590:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/AD11CC37-653F-44FD-B7E2-412C0DB10234/BadgerNew.app> (loaded)' with name 'FrontPageofBadger''
```

THere used to be a class and xib named FrontPageofBadger.

However, there is no reference to that anywhere in the whole project.

If I search the project for I got nothing.

So why, in the earth iOs try to load this so called FrontPageofBadger? There used to be a class named FrontPageofBadger. The class name changed to myprofile. I do not see any place where ios should find frontpageofbadger. It's not referred in any code or xib.

Where? And what kind of code try to load that?

Code runs fine in simulator

Yes others had the same problem. I have clean build delete from iPhone, etc. No avail

```
-(void)startInit{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"OnlyBookmark"];
    //[BNUtilitiesQuick AnimateSwitchingWithParent:self From:[BNUtilitiesQuick searchController] To:[BNUtilitiesQuick searchController]];



    if ([BNUtilitiesQuick searchController].view == nil) {};
    if ([BNUtilitiesQuick ListController].view == nil) {};
    if ([BNUtilitiesQuick FrontPageAje].view == nil) {}; //this is where the error happen. I
```

FrontPageAje is a function

```
+ (MyProfile *) FrontPageAje
{
    return[BNUtilitiesQuick appDelegate].SettingsMiscelaneous;
}
```

and it's declared here:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MyProfile *SettingsMiscelaneous;
```

It's very obvious that FrontPageofBadger doesn't show up anywhere.

I deliberately try to load all viewController in the beginning. Bad idea. I know.

Comment: try the 2nd an 3rd suggestions in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980296/xcode-includes-xib-files-that-have-been-deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess that one other nib File e.g. MainWindow.xib is referencing the missing nib file. Look what nibs are referenced in Interfacebuilder in a TabBarController or similar.